# help with a validation rule

Tags: validation, picklist, validation-rule

```
AND( 
  NOT( OR($User.ProfileId="00e30000000geag", 
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000vKto",
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000z2H8")
  ),
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( FAI_Status__c ),"DNS") ,
  ISCHANGED( FAI_Status__c ),
  OR(AND(
      ISPICKVAL(priorvalue(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c), "Clearing"),
      ISPICKVAL(priorvalue(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c), "Legal") )
  )
)
```

the above validation rule is for users, outside of the profiles listed, that can make a change on a custom picklist field called "FAI Status" when the option is DNS.  But those users cannot change the FAI Status from "DNS" when the Custom field called: DNS Reason has the following selections:  "Clearing" or "Legal"

the rule is written for both fields DNS and DNS reason but how do i write the rule if the user only changes the DNS reason field from Clearing or Legal?

example:

the record has FAI Status = DNS and DNS reason = Clearing.  user leaves FAI status at DNS but wants to change DNS reason to "non-clearing".

How do i write this rule?

Chad

Comment: Tip: Use `$Profile.name = "Foo"` instead of `$User.profileId = "someId"` - way more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you **create 2 seperate Validation Rules** for the 2 fields.. this will give you flexibility to change them independently and also to display a proper error message next to these fields

for the **FAIStatus field**, you can use the current one you have with the slight change of checking the current value (instead of priorvalue) of the reason field

```
AND( 
  NOT( OR($User.ProfileId="00e30000000geag", 
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000vKto",
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000z2H8")
  ),
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( FAI_Status__c ),"DNS") ,
  ISCHANGED( FAI_Status__c ),
  OR(
      ISPICKVAL(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c, "Clearing"),
      ISPICKVAL(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c, "Legal")
  )
)
```

and then have a similar one for the **DNSReason field** but check if the reason field got changed when the FAIStatus value is DNS

```
AND( 
  NOT( OR($User.ProfileId="00e30000000geag", 
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000vKto",
          $User.ProfileId="00e50000000z2H8")
  ),
  ISPICKVAL(FAI_Status__c ,"DNS") ,
  ISCHANGED( Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c ),
  OR(
      ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c), "Clearing"),
      ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Do_Not_Solicit_Reason__c), "Legal")
  )
)
```